# Preciso arrumar a imagem do slider

Tags: html, css

Estou usando um slider com imagens dentro, porem a imagem que eu coloquei nele é maior que a tela, dai ele corta parte da imagem e não fica centralizada. Eu não me importo que corte a imagem mas seria bom se ficasse centralizada.

Html:

```
    <div class="sliderprincipal">
        <div class="imgslider"> <img src="./img/imagem principal do slider.png"/> </div>
        <div class="imgslider"> <img src="./img/imagem principal do slider.png"/> </div>
        <div class="imgslider"> <img src="./img/imagem principal do slider.png"/> </div>
        <div class="imgslider"> <img src="./img/imagem principal do slider.png"/> </div>
      </div>      

</div>
```

Tem alguma forma de centralizar a imagem com css?
desde ja agradeço!

Answer (score -1):

Para centrar um elemento usa-se margem automática à esquerda e à direita.

```
    .imgslider img {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
```